# Make Lucene index a value and store another

Tags: lucene.net

I want Lucene.NET to store a value while indexing a modified, stripped-down version of the stored value. e.g. Consider the value:

```
this_example-has some/weird (chars) 100%
```

I want it stored right like that (so that I can retrieve exactly that for showing in the results list), but I want lucene to index it as:

```
this example has some weird chars 100
```

(you see, like a "sanitized" version of the original value) for a simplified search.

I figure this would be the job of an analyzer, but I don't want to mess with rolling my own. Ideally, the solution should remove everything that is not a letter, a number or quotes, replacing the removed chars by a white-space before indexing.

Any suggestions on how to implement that?

This is because I am indexing products for an e-commerce search, and some have realy creepy names. I think this would improve search assertiveness.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a custom analyzer, try storing the value as a separate non-indexed field, and use a simple regex to generate the sanitized version.

```
var input = "this_example-has some/weird (chars) 100%";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\W_]+", " ");
```

You mention that you need another Analyzer for some searching functionality. Dont forget the PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper which will allow you to use different analyzers within the same document.

```
public static void Main() {
    var wrapper = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(defaultAnalyzer: new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29));
    wrapper.AddAnalyzer(fieldName: "id", analyzer: new KeywordAnalyzer());

    IndexWriter writer = null; // TODO: Retrieve these.
    Document document = null;
    writer.AddDocument(document, analyzer: wrapper);
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the PerFieldAnalyzer, and it will surely come in handy! About the suggestion of having two separate fields, I think this will be the way to go, in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this is the work of the analyzer. And I'd start by using a tool like [luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to see what the standard analyzer does with your term before getting into what to use -- it tends to do a good job stripping noise characters and words.

Comment: I did look into it, and unfortunately it doesn't behave the way I need  it to.. It transformed **[this_example-has some/weird (chars) 100%]** into **["example has"
"some weird" chars 100]**. But it didn't do the same for **[meta-6]**, whereas it remained **[meta-6]**.  Moreover, the system needs to index and search product names in brazilian portuguese, and for that I need to use a different analyzer (BrazilianAnalyzer). That's why I thought it would be easier to have separated values for retrieval and searching... any thoughts?